# VS2019 Setup project for windows service doesn't add the service to the services list

Tags: windows-services, visual-studio-2019, setup-project

I've built a Windows Service in vs2019 using C# but in order to test it I need to install it. I have built a VS Setup project and I can see this is installing the files into a sub-directory of Program Files (x86), but it isn't adding it to the services list.

I'm new to creating Setup projects, but I do have an existing project built by someone else which I have been using as a guide. As far as I can see I have everything set up correctly, so there must be something not obvious that I'm missing.

I've tried googling the issue but, as usual, there are millions of results but none of them apply to my situation. I'm really hoping someone can point me in the right direction as my experience on Stack Overflow has been disappointing so far.

Answer (score 0):

So, yet again I have to answer my own question. It seems that as well as creating a Setup project I also needed to add an installer to my service. I did this by:

1. Double click the .cs for the service
2. Right click on the grey panel that appears and select Add Installer
3. Select each of the two items that appear in the grey panel and set their properties to appropriate values (Description, DisplayName, ServiceName, StartType, Account etc).

I think ideally this should be done before the setup project is created as it took me several attempts to get the service to install correctly this way around.